# Using shared object across threads (Parallel.for) throws Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am using Parallel.for to process batch of Employees with multiple threads.

The SqlHelper is declared globally at class level:

```
Private _dataAccess As SqlHelper
```

> Method that uses a shared SqlHelper:

```
Private Sub FillHashForBatch(ByVal threadcount As Integer, ByRef EmployeeHash As Hashtable)
    Dim Query As New StringBuilder
    Dim ImportEmpInfoReader As SqlDataReader

    Try

        Query=getQuery()

        ImportEmpInfoReader = _dataAccess.ExecuteReader(Query.ToString())

    Catch customException As ExceptionHandler

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The Application throws "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**" in Sub FillHashForBatch()
All other variable I've used are local for that method except _dataAccess which is global.

> My Questions are:

1. If these variables are local, each thread will have its own instance of variable. is this true? If yes they might bot be causing error.
2. If the shared SqlHelper is causing error, because its shared, why it's throwing "Object reference" error? Is any thread making it null after use?
3. I was only able to find error is occurred in this method, and not exact line because its not possible to debug and error occures randomly. Not always. How can I find exact line?
4. Last but not least, what is solution?

Comment: Remove all exception catches - and you will get exact line and full information about exception

Comment: If you want save time in findings errors - never catch exception if you not going to handle it. Thrown exception is your best helper in finding bugs

Comment: @Fabio thanks for suggestion. But as this is code from our organisation I could not post all code. The catch block contains some lines for tracking of error on production.

Comment: Then you can check that log for your exception

Comment: Thank you! any comments on other questions? coz that's my main concern

Comment: _If these variables are local, each thread will have its own instance of variable_ -  true

Comment: About `SqlHelper`: 1. Are you sure you have initialized your `_dataAccess` variable before using it? 2. You need to show code of  `SqlHelper` class.

Comment: Yes @Fabio. It is initialized. many times even the query is executed properly. As i said, the error is Random. If it was not initialized,  It would have never worked.

Comment: Based on _even the query is executed properly_ and _the error is Random_ I think error caused by the data returned from database.

Comment: Use `ex.ToString()` to get full information about exception

Comment: Are you sure that `getQuery` method always return not `null'`?

Comment: @VMAtm yes. I've manually assigned value to Query as "Select A from ... "

Comment: Then you have to examine full stacktrace with `.ToString` method